# MySQL SELECT JOIN 3 таблицы, LIMIT 1

Tags: c#, mysql, select, limit

Всем добра. Возникли трудности, работая с 3-мя таблицами.

Таблицы: **users, schedule_canceled, set_phone**

[image: users][image: schedule_canceled] [image: set_phone]

Таблица 1: **users** в ней находятся пользователи (есть индивидуальный идентификатор **u_login**

Таблица 2: **schedule_canceled** в ней находятся отмененные записи клиентов (пользователей) - идентификатор **sc_login** и дата отмен. записи **sc_date**

Таблица 3: **set_phone** в ней находятся номера телефонов пользователей (их несколько) - идентификатор **sp_login**, сортировать нужный номер необходимо по дате **sp_date** (первый по возрастанию)

**Задача:**
Вывести отменные записи пользователей из **users** забрать **users_snm**, из **schedule_canceled** все данные, а вот из **set_phone** лишь первый номер телефона.

Моя попытка, выводит нужную запись, НО дублируя её числом количеством номеров пользователя.

```
String request = "SELECT schedule_canceled.*, users.u_snm, (SELECT sp_phone FROM set_phone where users.u_login = set_phone.sp_login LIMIT 1) AS sp_phone FROM users LEFT JOIN schedule_canceled ON schedule_canceled.sc_user_id = users.u_login LEFT JOIN set_phone on users.u_login = set_phone.sp_login WHERE schedule_canceled.sc_date = '" + _dateTime.Value.ToShortDateString() + "'";
```

Спасибо.

Comment: *лишь первый номер телефона* Первый - по какому признаку? при какой сортировке?

Comment: @Alkina, первый в таблице номеров для этого **sp_login**

Comment: Вы слово "сортировка" видите? вот и укажите, по какой комбинации полей сортировать. Пока нет сортировки, нет даже самого понятия порядка записей. А лучше подумайте - может, устроит любой из имеющихся? запрос получится гораздо проще...

Comment: @Alkina, номера можно сортировать по дате **sp_date**, по возрастанию первый.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте туда эту информацию. А также опишите и местоположение указанного поля.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u.*, sc.*, (SELECT phone
                   FROM set_phone
                   WHERE sp_login = u.u_login
                   ORDER BY sp_date ASC
                   LIMIT 1) phone
FROM users u
JOIN schedule_canceled sc ON u.u_login =sc.sc_login
```

Comment: спасибо, всё верно.